# How do I change the home folder for an user used by process sshd?

Tags: sshd, home, user-mode-linux

I'm logged as `root`. Need to change home folder of another user but when I run `usermod -d /path/to/new/home myuser` it returns:

```
usermod: user myuser is being used by process xxxx
```

Said process is `sshd`. What do I do now? I'd rather not having to restart the server.

Note: it's a remote server. Will killing `sshd` also log me out (I'm logged as root, not as myuser)?

Comment: Who owns the `sshd` process in question?  Would the owner be the user of the account you are trying to change?  You will have multiple `sshd` processes if you have multiple users of your system.